# How can I elevate a double type of data to a power, in the language of Dart?

Tags: dart

How can I elevate a double type of data to a power, in the language of Dart

for instance

1.08 raised to 2.05 
because with the pow() function provided by dart:math I can only assign integer values .

I'm new. Sorry if the question is silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with double. The `pow` function parameters are of type `num` which can be `int` or `double`
 
An example here

```
void main(){
  print(pow(1.08,2.05));
}
```

Consider updating dart.

Comment: Hello Jot, Welcome to SO. Please post solution to a question rather than a reference .